# Error handling in for comprehension

Tags: scala, sequence, for-comprehension

I have some list to browse but i whant to know if there is some touble in the browsing exemple :

```
val feedChildrens =  for {
   persone <- cities.getCitizens
   child <- personne.getChildrens
} yield {
   child give cake
   child
}
feedChildens match {
  case Nil => "Error no child feed"
  case _ => "Go purshace more cake !"
}
```

but with this system we could not have precise error like "Error this is a gost city" and "Error there is children in this city".

I know i could do somthing with match case like this

```
persone <- cities.getCitizens match {
  case Nil => "Error this is a gost city"
  case parents :List[Parent]   => parents.flatMap( _.getChildrens ) match {
                      case Nil => ""Error there is children in this city".
                      case  childrens :List[Children] => 
                                            childrens.map{child => 
                                                    child give cake
                                                    child 
                                             }
}
```

But it's look ugly and I lose the `for-comprehension`
I try also to think about, but it's seem to use only `Exception` 
(I would like to have simple objects for my error) 
I and the monad try are use before the sequences monad in the `for-comprehension`, what is great but block me.

So I wonder if it's possible to have a clean way to report error during the `for-comprehension`

Comment: Have you considered using Try?  http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/26/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try.html

Answer (score 3):

If you want to "fail fast" and report the first error you encounter, then a `Try` is what you're looking for.

When you compose `Try` instances, you'll get a `Success[T]` if everything went smooth and a `Failure[E]` in case something failed, where the `Failure` is the first one occurred.

If you instead need to accumulate the errors, then a monad is not the appropriate abstraction, as monad composition is designed to cut the chain as soon as possible: you'll need something more powerful (technically speaking an applicative functor), like the `Validation` provided by `scalaz`.

Comment: Yes i need to "fail fast" but i have considered using Try but the Failure can contain Only Exception.
And how mix Try and Seq in for comprehension?